# XNA - Signing in with Local Profile

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to learn XNA (4.0) multiplayer networking for the PC only environment.

For development, I read that using local profiles (with SystemLink) for PC-only environment does not require me to worry about Xbox Live Licenses. Using

```
Guide.ShowSignIn (1,false);
```

causes the Xbox Live sign-in to come up. But I am stuck here. The sign-in seems to demand a live profile (as opposed to a local one?). When I log on with my live profile, the following exception is thrown:

> The current profile does not have an XNA Creators Club membership, which is required to sign in to the LIVE service. To continue, purchase a membership from Xbox LIVE Marketplace, or switch to a local gamer profile.

My question is: HOW do I switch to a local gamer profile?

I've searched, I've looked at code...

I just know there is a dead-stupid simple answer, but darned if I can find it....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yup, I knew it was stupid!

When you hit "Create new Profile" it seems that your only option is to create a new Live profile....

However, if you happen to notice, there is a scroll bar, and when you scroll down, you see there is a link that lets you create a local profile! Nice how they hid that, and somehow I didn't notice the scrollbar.

Feeling very stupid...

Comment: I just hit the exact same problem and didn't notice the damn scroll bar either. I'm glad you posted this here!

Comment: When I click "Create new profile" it does not take me to that infamous screen where you could scroll down. It just shows a message that tells me that it will open a new browser window to create a new profile. Help!